# Android GridLayout.Spec

Tags: android, android-layout, grid-layout

I am working on an app and use the [GridLayout.Spec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.Spec.html) to set row and column span programmatically. But there is a problem: If i start the app on an AVD with API 16 everything works fine. If i start it on an AVD or Handy with API 15 the row and columnSpan does not change.

GridLayout.Spec should be available since API 14 so where is the problem?

```
FrameLayout container = (FrameLayout) widget.getParent();
GridLayout.LayoutParams params = (android.widget.GridLayout.LayoutParams) container
        .getLayoutParams();
(...)
params.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(widget.getPosition().x, columnSpan);
params.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(widget.getPosition().y, rowSpan);
container.setLayoutParams(params);
```

The widget is my own class.

Answer (score 0):

There is support library that contains GridLayout, maybe you could try to use that.